# Coroutines don't seem to be less resource-intensive than JVM threads

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I've done a benchmark(referenced to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112104/11523294)) to test the memory use between coroutiens and threads in a thread pool:

```kotlin
val COUNT = 4_000

val executor: Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())// 12 cores on my machine
 fun main(array: Array<String>)  = runBlocking{
     val latch = CountDownLatch(COUNT)
     val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
     repeat(COUNT) {
         launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
             testByCoroutine(latch)
         }
     }
     latch.await()
     println("total: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))


     // testByThreadPool()
 }


fun testByThreadPool() {
    val latch = CountDownLatch(COUNT)
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    for (i in 0..<COUNT) {
        executor.execute {
            val num: Int = request1()
            println(request2(num))
            latch.countDown()
        }
    }
    try {
        latch.await()
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
    println("total: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
    exitProcess(0)
}

fun testByCoroutine(latch: CountDownLatch) {
    val num = request1()
    val res: Int = request2(num)
    println(res)
    latch.countDown()
}


fun request1(): Int {
    return doGet("https://bing.com")
}

fun request2(token: Int): Int {
    val response: Int = doGet("https://bing.com")
    return response + token
}

fun doGet(link: String): Int {
    try {
        val url = URL(link)
        val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET")
        conn.setConnectTimeout(3000)
        return conn.getResponseCode()
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return -1
}
```

The thread pool case:

```
total: 518218
```

[image]
The Dispatchers.Default case:

```
total: 561510
```

[image]

The Dispatchers.IO case:

```
total: 262719
```

[image]

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48107357/11523294):

```
Coroutines are not designed to be faster than threads, it is for lower RAM consumption
```

There's a [benchmark](https://www.techyourchance.com/kotlin-coroutines-vs-threads-memory-benchmark/) says that there seems to be relatively constant ratio of 6:1 in the consumed memory between a thread and a coroutine.

But I didn't see any evident difference on memory use between coroutines and thread pool from above graphs.

Am I designing the benchmark wrong?

Comment: Coroutines don’t provide a memory or speed advantage over thread pools. “Lightweight thread” means lightweight in comparison to spinning up a new thread per task, which isn’t what you have when using a thread pool. And the continuation machinery under the hood of coroutines is an additional burden in comparison to a basic thread pool.

Comment: `“Lightweight thread” means lightweight in comparison to spinning up a new thread per task` So that's it.
I did a test and it does take very little memory to create a coroutine compared to creating a thread for each task. But nowadays, no one is going to create a thread for each task by using `new Thread`, in that case then I don't think there is any advantage of coroutine in real programming work, thread pool is enough.

Comment: But the syntax of coroutines for async calls is pretty good

Comment: It's primarily for structured concurrency. The syntax is a huge bonus, too. No more "callback hell".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: by saying coroutines are lighter than threads we usually mean we can launch thousands or even millions of concurrent coroutines - which we can't do with threads. We can go back to old, easy to use model of starting a new "thread" per task. We can split tasks into subtasks by simply launching even more "threads". We won't get out of memory problems, all coroutines will run concurrently, we won't have to queue tasks explicitly and at the same time resources will be used optimally.

For many, many years we struggle in concurrent processing to provide somewhat contradicting properties:

1. Utilize possibly all CPUs all the time (as long as we have something to do).
2. Keep the number of threads low as they induce overhead:

- Idle/waiting threads - ideally, as close to 0 as possible. They consume memory, doing nothing.
- Active threads, especially CPU-intensive - run at most the number of CPUs of them (or 2x CPUs). Otherwise, threads fight for access to CPU, decreasing the performance.

3. Keep the code simple.

Most of concurrency models provide 2 of these properties, but compromising the third.

Your examples don't provide 1. You utilize resources in a very inefficient way, because your application is idling almost all the time, while it has a long queue of tasks to process.

Long, long ago we would use a model where we would start one thread per task - that provides 1. and 3., but obviously doesn't meet 2.

We could use a thread pool of say 50 threads. This is a very easy to do (3.), and by choosing the number of threads we balance between meeting 1. and 2. Lower number may mean all threads are waiting, wasting CPU. Higher numbers means we need more memory for threads and we potentially process too many tasks at once, so they have to fight for access to CPU. Also each task has to allocate some memory for its data, so optimally, we should process as little tasks as possible to only meet 1. With a thread pool we can't control this fully. We can only experiment with the number of threads to get the best compromise, but this requires some work and is still far from optimal.

Because of the above, we started using asynchronous models: callbacks, futures, reactive streams, etc. They provide 1. and 2., so they schedule tasks and use resources in a very efficient manner, but they are terrible for 3.

Coroutines do pretty much the same underneath to other asynchronous models, they have very similar properties for 1. and 2., but they allow to keep the code as simple as in the "long, long ago" case - simply spawn a coroutine per task and that's it. We write the code top-to-bottom, we can smoothly switch between CPU-intensive, waiting in I/O or waiting on synchronization with other tasks, we can easily split a task into concurrent subtasks, then join again, etc. - all of this while still keeping the code resource-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct comparison should be between coroutines and async programming. These two have about the same footprint and solve the same problems in terms of resource usage. In short, the problem they solve is having a huge number of concurrent tasks that spend most of their time waiting for IO. This problem can't be solved with thread pools and blocking IO.

Now, the advantage of coroutines over async programming comes down to code simplicity, readability, and scoping. A coroutine allows you to write simple sequential code which gets transformed internally to the async-style programming style. In addition to the obvious advantage of regular-looking code vs. a forest of nested callbacks, a great advantage is that you get back the simplicity of exceptions that automatically propagate up the call stack, whereas with async programming you have to pay meticulous attention to `OnError`-type callbacks everywhere, with very complex error paths.