# How coroutines in kotlin work internally, how they utilise resources, why they are more resource-intensive than threads

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm something near zero in kotlin and no matter how much I tried to figure it out, read, watch, I still don't get it. How coroutines in kotlin work internally, how they utilise resources, why they are more resource-intensive than threads. Please explain it in as much detail as possible.

I watched lectures about coroutines and readed 2 articles and still cant answer my questions, so i asking for help with them.

Comment: It is really hard to explain in a few sentences. Coroutines are not more resource-intensive than threads. They don't provide a better performance in general. They allow to use resources efficiently while keeping the code relatively simple. You could read my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77401506/448875

Comment: You could also have a look at [this article](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-coroutines-animated-part-1-coroutine-hello-world-51797d8b9cd4), which walks you through how you can build the coroutines framework on top of the language primitives / compiler intrinsics

Comment: I don't know who told you that coroutines "are more resource-intensive than threads", but it's the opposite: Coroutines are much cheaper than Threads. That's the entire point of them.

Comment: @Jorn I think OP meant that coroutines utilize resources in a more efficient way, utilize them "more". It is kind of funny, because in the link provided by me someone asked, why/how coroutines are less resource-intensive than threads, and here OP asked why/how they are more resource-intensive ;-) But I suspect they both asked the same thing, only used contradicting phrases to describe it.

Comment: @broot I still doesn't get, how coroutines more resource-intensive? How they utilize resources in a more efficient way? Please describe

Comment: Making long story short, the idea is that each CPU executes a single thread, which executes a single coroutine and whenever the coroutine has to wait for something, the thread/CPU switches to executing another coroutine. This is the most efficient way of using modern CPUs, we used this model even before coroutines, but now it is easier to do. Of course, the above is an ideal case, in practice it is not that smooth, but we try to keep as close to this as possible.